# Subtract one number range from another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have number interval from X to Y (for example x = 100, y = 200, so interval is 100, 101, ... 200) and have table with two columns "from" and "two", which means another interval like:

```
from    to
110    120
130    140
```

I need to subtract from range (100, 200) all ranges in the table (from, to).
So, the result will be those ranges within the original range that are not part of ranges in the table.

```
100 109 
121 129 
141 200
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Where does 100 and 20 come from?

Comment: This is a bit rough to understand. I am not sure what you are asking. Could you perhaps be a bit more clear in what is being subtracted from what?

Comment: What are you subtracting? Why did 110 become 100 but 120 become 109?  Where did the 141 and 200 row come from?

Comment: yes, x = 100, y = 200 are coming from.

Comment: Why did 110 become 100 but 120 become 109?
We have interval from 100 to 200, and another interval from 110 to 120, so it is 110, 111, 112,... 120.
After subtraction initial interval will
from 100 to 109, and from 121 to 200

Answer (score 5):

One way would be ([DEMO](https://rextester.com/VOUB20215))

```
DECLARE @X INT = 100,
        @Y INT = 200;

WITH N(N)
     AS (SELECT @X
         UNION ALL
         SELECT N + 1
         FROM   N
         WHERE  N < @Y),
     T1
     AS (SELECT N,
                NewGrp = CASE WHEN N = 1 + LAG(N) OVER (ORDER BY N) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
         FROM   N
         WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM   #intervals
                            WHERE  N BETWEEN [from] AND [to])),
     T2
     AS (SELECT N,
                Grp = SUM(NewGrp) OVER (ORDER BY N ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
         FROM   T1)
SELECT MIN(N),
       MAX(N)
FROM   T2
GROUP  BY Grp
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10000)
```

You could simplify things and make it a bit more efficient by using a permanent numbers table instead of a recursive CTE